# Port is listening but unable to connect

Tags: c, sockets

I have disabled firewall, made entries in the /etc/hosts. Port is showing listening in lsof -i -P and netstat -antlp command.

```
netstat -antlp| grep 16000
tcp 0 0  192.168.1.50:16000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2405/rsrtd

lsof -i -P | grep 16000
rsrtd 2405 root 3u IPv4 19628 0t0 TCP Redhat:16000 (LISTEN)
```

Also when i am trying to do telnet it showing connecting but not showing login prompt.
ping is happening.

What else needs to be checked? Any idea..

Comment: Does telnet actually connect? Is your C process actually calling `accept`?

Comment: If telnet indicates you're connected, you're connected. Whether you get a login prompt depends on what you're connected *to.* If you're getting 'connection refused', you aren't connected. Make up your mind. Which is it?

Comment: Can you show your code to us?

Comment: @EJP Actually i figured it out. What you are saying is correct. through telnet it is connecting the port but on the client program as i made silly mistake it is going in error condition. That's why i am getting different errors for both,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All for the response.

I have figured it out the problem. Actually port was listening correct. There was very silly mistake in my program. In client program i compared the error with "!=0"  in connect call that's why if even call is succeeded it is going in error condition. Also same thing i done with the bind call. I replaced them with < 0 and in the server program  in the accept call i made entries for the client. Initially i was using 0.